# How does django know where to load login.html

Tags: django

I have used the following steps to create a login page.

1> create the `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^$', main_page),
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

2> create `registration/login.html`

3> load `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` then I see the created login.html.

Also my directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── bookmarks
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── bookmarksdb
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── site_media
│   └── style.css
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── main_page.html
│   ├── registration
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── logout_success.html
│   │   ├── register.html
│   │   └── register_success.html
│   ├── user_page.html
└── urls.py
```

Question> How does django know to connect the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` with `template\registration\login.html`?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you look in `django.contrib.auth.views.py` you'll find

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html'),
      redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      current_app=None, extra_context=None):
"""
Displays the login form and handles the login action.
"""
```

it's simply the default template path, which you can override should you wish

Comment: by doing: (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'my_login_template.html'})